# App keeps crashing when Android profiler is used

Tags: android, profiler

My app is doing some location tracking and update database when needed, the app has been running 2 days without having any issue. And now I am trying to use the Android Profiler (Android Studio 3.01), however, as soon as I turn it, it runs for few seconds and then it starts crashing the app. Anyone has an idea?

```
10-22 21:31:01.236 16471-16471/myproject.myfirstapp A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 16471 (ampaigns.myfirstapp), pid 16471 (ampaigns.myfirstapp)
10-22 21:31:01.358 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-22 21:31:01.358 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/taimen/taimen:9/PPR2.181005.003/4984323:user/release-keys'
10-22 21:31:01.358 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG: Revision: 'rev_10'
10-22 21:31:01.358 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
10-22 21:31:01.358 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG: pid: 16471, tid: 16471, name: ampaigns.myfirstapp  >>> myproject.myfirstapp <<<
10-22 21:31:01.358 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
10-22 21:31:01.358 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000004057  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000000000000008
10-22 21:31:01.358 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     x4  000000000000000a  x5  000000000000000a  x6  000000000000000a  x7  000000000000000a
10-22 21:31:01.359 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     x8  0000000000000083  x9  00000077c95b99d8  x10 fffffff87ffffbdf  x11 0000000000000001
10-22 21:31:01.359 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     x12 0000000000000064  x13 0000000000000000  x14 00000000ffffffff  x15 0000007fdd2337b8
10-22 21:31:01.359 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     x16 00000077c95f22c8  x17 00000077c95302d8  x18 0000007fdd23313a  x19 0000000000004057
10-22 21:31:01.359 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     x20 0000000000004057  x21 0000000000000083  x22 0000000004000000  x23 0000000000000000
10-22 21:31:01.359 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     x24 000000773f7f1640  x25 0000007fdd233b38  x26 0000000000000000  x27 000000773f7f1640
10-22 21:31:01.359 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     x28 0000007747a6d460  x29 0000007fdd233800
10-22 21:31:01.359 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     sp  0000007fdd2337c0  lr  00000077c9524a90  pc  00000077c9524abc
10-22 21:31:01.606 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
10-22 21:31:01.606 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0000000000021abc  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+124)
10-22 21:31:01.606 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0000000000066ad4  /data/data/myproject.myfirstapp/libperfa_arm64.so
10-22 21:31:01.606 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0000000000072c48  /data/data/myproject.myfirstapp/libperfa_arm64.so
10-22 21:31:01.606 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0000000000072890  /data/data/myproject.myfirstapp/libperfa_arm64.so
10-22 21:31:01.606 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000000000052058  /data/data/myproject.myfirstapp/libperfa_arm64.so
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00000000000910b0  /system/lib64/libopenjdkjvmti.so (_ZN12openjdkjvmti11Transformer26TransformSingleClassDirectILNS_13ArtJvmtiEventE85EEEvPNS_12EventHandlerEPN3art6ThreadEPNS_18ArtClassDefinitionE+1864)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0000000000091c48  /system/lib64/libopenjdkjvmti.so (openjdkjvmti::Transformer::RetransformClasses(openjdkjvmti::ArtJvmTiEnv*, openjdkjvmti::EventHandler*, art::Runtime*, art::Thread*, int, _jclass* const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*)+768)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0000000000039f90  /system/lib64/libopenjdkjvmti.so (openjdkjvmti::JvmtiFunctions::RetransformClasses(_jvmtiEnv*, int, _jclass* const*)+192)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 0000000000053e40  /data/data/myproject.myfirstapp/libperfa_arm64.so
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 00000000004b2828  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ti::AgentSpec::DoLoadHelper(_JNIEnv*, bool, _jobject*, int*, art::ti::LoadError*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*)+832)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 00000000004b2e78  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ti::AgentSpec::Attach(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, int*, art::ti::LoadError*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*)+120)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0000000000476c30  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::AttachAgent(_JNIEnv*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&, _jobject*)+1312)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 00000000003d325c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::VMDebug_nativeAttachAgent(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jstring*, _jobject*)+1908)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 0000000000079a48  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (offset 0x78000) (dalvik.system.VMDebug.nativeAttachAgent [DEDUPED]+200)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 000000000055cc4c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+604)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 00000000000cf760  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+232)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 00000000002823b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+344)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 000000000027c36c  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+948)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #18 pc 000000000052d8dc  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+204)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #19 pc 000000000054f214  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #20 pc 000000000018fa0c  /system/framework/boot-core-libart.vdex (dalvik.system.VMDebug.attachAgent)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #21 pc 0000000000255e68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2146680767+496)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #22 pc 000000000025b9e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #23 pc 000000000027c350  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #24 pc 000000000052d8dc  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+204)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #25 pc 000000000054f214  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #26 pc 00000000004b5f4a  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.app.ActivityThread.attemptAttachAgent)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #27 pc 0000000000255e68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2146680767+496)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #28 pc 000000000025b9e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #29 pc 000000000027c350  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #30 pc 000000000052d8dc  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+204)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #31 pc 000000000054f214  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #32 pc 00000000004b7eca  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.app.ActivityThread.handleAttachAgent+18)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #33 pc 0000000000255e68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2146680767+496)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #34 pc 000000000025b9e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #35 pc 000000000027c350  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #36 pc 000000000052d8dc  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+204)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #37 pc 000000000054f214  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #38 pc 000000000037f02e  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage+222)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #39 pc 0000000000255e68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2146680767+496)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #40 pc 000000000025b9e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #41 pc 000000000027c350  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #42 pc 000000000052c3d8  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+584)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #43 pc 000000000054f094  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #44 pc 0000000000ae3442  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+42)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #45 pc 0000000000255e68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2146680767+496)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #46 pc 000000000025b9e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #47 pc 000000000027c350  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
10-22 21:31:01.607 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #48 pc 000000000052c3d8  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+584)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #49 pc 000000000054f094  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #50 pc 0000000000aea530  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.os.Looper.loop+404)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #51 pc 0000000000255e68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2146680767+496)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #52 pc 000000000025b9e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #53 pc 000000000027c350  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #54 pc 000000000052d8dc  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+204)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #55 pc 000000000054f214  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #56 pc 0000000000384a52  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.app.ActivityThread.main+214)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #57 pc 0000000000255e68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2146680767+496)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #58 pc 000000000051cb18  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1032)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #59 pc 0000000000565afc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #60 pc 000000000055cc4c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+604)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #61 pc 00000000000cf760  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+232)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #62 pc 00000000004633b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #63 pc 0000000000464e10  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1440)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #64 pc 00000000003f43b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+48)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #65 pc 000000000011e6d4  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (offset 0x114000) (java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal [DEDUPED]+180)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #66 pc 000000000055c988  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #67 pc 00000000000cf740  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #68 pc 00000000002823b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+344)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #69 pc 000000000027c36c  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+948)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #70 pc 000000000052c3d8  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+584)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #71 pc 000000000054f094  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #72 pc 0000000000c0b2f6  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+22)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #73 pc 0000000000255e68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2146680767+496)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #74 pc 000000000051cb18  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1032)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #75 pc 0000000000565afc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #76 pc 0000000000bea920  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3cd000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+3088)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #77 pc 000000000055cc4c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+604)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #78 pc 00000000000cf760  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+232)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #79 pc 00000000004633b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #80 pc 0000000000463010  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+416)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #81 pc 0000000000366854  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+644)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #82 pc 00000000000b1bf8  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+120)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #83 pc 00000000000b4578  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+760)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #84 pc 00000000000021a0  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1200)
10-22 21:31:01.608 16585-16585/? A/DEBUG:     #85 pc 00000000000ae760  /system/lib64/libc.so (__libc_init+88)
```

Comment: Updated Android Studio to 3.2.1 resolved problem

Comment: With AS 3.3.1 have the same issue (

Comment: I have the same issue using AS 3.3.1 when running the app on an Android 9 device (Pixel 2), but it works fine on Android 7.0 (LG-G5). Can you share your device/emulator details?

Comment: Same here for AS 3.3.1 and Pixel 2 (9.0)

Comment: I have the same issue with both AS 3.3.1 and 3.3.2. I think it worked on AS 3.3.1 before I upgraded my Samsung Galaxy S8 to pie (API 28)

Comment: Same here AS3.4 and Samsung Galaxy s8.

Comment: Is your package name is `myproject.myfirstapp`? On what device were you testing? Was it emulator? Which one? Did you run a debug version or prod build?

Comment: make sure to disable before build new APK by open  Run configuration >>app>>profiling>>remove check mark from "Enable advanced profiling "

Comment: you have to write new location based code for android pie

Comment: Report it to google with a reproduction of the issue. They will look into it.
I reported a crash through the Profiler as well: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133166400

Comment: Please read my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50542969/8572503

Comment: @spiderloop please add your resolution as answer to make that question answered

Comment: @spiderloop, I have faced the same issue, as soon as I open profiler app keep, showing the ANR dialog or after a while app crashes. Do not try to interact with UI or produce touches on the app until profiler starts completely, as it looks like profiler is trying to extract the app info from the app. But after profile starts It works normally without any ANR dialogs or crashes. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 9):

It perhaps an android studio profile bug. Delete the whole codecache directory in your application data package root path(data/data/pacakge_name/codecache) and retry profile again.

Comment: this worked inmediately, no more crashes but now I don't have the advanced profiler  : /

Comment: to remove the folder: `adb shell "run-as <your-app-package> rm -R /data/data/<your-app-package>/code_cache"`
although it didn't work for me (android studio 4.2.3). weirdly enough, problem started once I added debuggable: true, and wasn't fixed once removed.

Answer (score 4):

In Android Studio 4.0 (or higher), the following is the navigation to avoid crashes when running with profiler:

```
1. From menu click on "Run"
2. Profile 'app'
```

Comment: Excellent, this solved it. On Huawei devices I was able to run the profiler for 5 seconds and then this crash. On samsung devices, the application completely froze when starting the profiler thanks !

Comment: Didn't help me for my Huawei P40 Pro

Answer (score 0):

`signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL)` means the `abort` was deliberate.

This issue seems to be related: [Profiler crashes in libperfa_arm64.so](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110924477)

Answer (score 0):

Is your app a fairly sizable project with a large number of classes, potentially with some custom class loader logic?

Once you are able have the steps to reproduce the crash, you can use a tool like **logcat** to get more information.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in Android Studio 4.0 with an Android 9.0 (Pie) device:

E/libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 17635 (Jit thread pool), pid 17630