# Android Studio causes application to receive Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL)

Tags: java, android

So essentially, my application was working with no errors, until I restarted my computer. Now, whenever I attempt to run the application from within Android Studio, the application crashes after a few seconds (with no interaction) with the following output:

```
    03-08 13:57:30.175 16138-16138/com.aryangulati.ddapppt2 V/StudioProfiler: StudioProfilers agent attached.
    03-08 13:57:30.210 16138-16203/com.aryangulati.ddapppt2 V/StudioProfiler: Acquiring Application for Events
    03-08 13:57:30.367 16138-16138/com.aryangulati.ddapppt2 A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 16138 (gulati.ddapppt2), pid 16138 (gulati.ddapppt2)
```

Surprisingly, this error only occurs when my device is plugged into my laptop. When I opened the application directly on my phone, unplugged from the computer, it functions normally. However, whenever the device is plugged into the laptop and/or I run it from the IDE, it causes a crash. I have tried restarting Android Studio, but the same problem still occurs. Why does this happen? And what can I do to fix it?

**Edit:** I found this thread: [Android app crashes with SIGABRT Signal 6 only while Eclipse debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595778/android-app-crashes-with-sigabrt-signal-6-only-while-eclipse-debugging), but for some reason, I cannot find the show all ANRs option in the developer settings. Any help there would also be appreciated.

**Edit 2:** I have found this only occurs when attempting to use the android profiler

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android app crashes with SIGABRT Signal 6 only while Eclipse debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595778/android-app-crashes-with-sigabrt-signal-6-only-while-eclipse-debugging)

Comment: Not sure if this is just me, but I cannot seem to find the "show all ANRs" option in my developer options, is it possible it was removed (android 9)?

Comment: @AryanGulati , I think the option was renamed to "Show background ANRs"...also, when the ANR/crash dialog appears for me, it doesn't ask me if I would like to wait for the application to respond because it is already dead :(

Comment: related SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52940401/app-keeps-crashing-when-android-profiler-is-used

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio 4.0 (or higher), there is a specific way to run the app with Profiler:

1. From menu click on "Run"
2. Profile 'app'

With this mode, app does not crash.

Comment: Nice! But how can I return to my beatyfull debug mode ?

Answer (score 1):

add this permission in manifeast ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE || fix this problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!